# How far will my car roll given a function representing the slope of the landscape I'm driving on?

Tags: calculus, physics

So I was driving in my car thinking to myself "I wonder how far I would go (before starting to roll backwards) if I just took my foot off the brakes" I tried to figure it out myself but could not. SO I am asking the smartest people in the world, you guys!

Parameters: Write a generalized equation representing the distance a car travels based on f(x) and any other physical constants/variables needed. f(x) is a function that represents the cross section of the road you are traveling on. Thus the slope at any given point represents the angle of the road. You may treat the car as a box sliding with friction.

Comment: What kind of friction?  The dependence of frictional force on velocity can be a complicated thing.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Most vehicle dynamics models consider rolling resistance and drag as the two primary sources of friction. Any more complicated models are linearized, localized, and typically wrapped into the rolling resistance model. For higher-fidelity dynamics, we might consider terrain factors, etc., but for this question, that's almost certainly immaterial -- just wrap it into the rolling resistance constant.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple situation of force balancing. Enumerate all the forces on the car:

- **Gravity:** $F_g = mg\cos \theta$;
- **Rolling resistance:** $F_R = C_R v$;
- **Drag:** $F_D = C_D v^2$;
- **Power:** $F_A$

The sum of these forces must be zero. Drag and rolling resistance act in the opposite direction of motion. The gravity term depends on orientation. Without losing generality, we can write the equation of motion as:
$$0 = F_A - F_D - F_R + F_g \\
C_R\frac{dx}{dt} + C_D \left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2 - mg\cos \theta = F_A.$$

If we have no acceleration (equiv. no braking), then $F_A = 0$. Of course, $\theta$ is measured as the angle with respect to level ground. This angle may change relative to the $x$-position, so it may be more appropriate to consider the gravity term as $mg\cos \theta(x)$.

Comment: This assumes 1-D motion, which appears to be your situation.

Comment: There had better be acceleration, or I'll never get my car out of the driveway.  The velocity is not expected to be constant.  You need a term $m \dfrac{d^2 x}{dt^2}$.

Comment: That's $ F_a $. If the driveway is a hill, then the acceleration is in the gravity term.

Comment: @Arkamis How does one account for the fact that the car might not be in contact with the road at all (depending on its speed and the profile of the road ahead)?

Comment: @user_of_math In such a scenario, I would bring a change of underwear.

Comment: But in all seriousness, you set the rolling resistance coefficient to zero in such a case. The drag term, in practice, will not change very much. There is an effect from the ground on the drag coefficient, but we're not talking about flying cars. If you wanted to analyze a stunt car, you would break it into cases: one case after leaving the ramp (with a drag coefficient reflecting the expected angle of attack etc. in glide conditions), and a second case before leaving the ramp (where rolling resistance matters).